# watch perldoc output preserving formatting

Tags: perl, watch

When I use `watch` to follow a `perlpod` documentation i am writing, the formatting gets mangeled (see `NAME` and `Synopsis` sections):

```
Every 2,0s: perldoc lib/Uki/Handlers/SOS.pm                                                   Tue Apr  8 10:42:43 2014

Uki::Handlers::SOS(3) User Contributed Perl DocumentationUki::Handlers::SOS(3)



N NA AM ME E
       Uki::Handlers::SOS - Studenten-Handler

S Sy yn no op ps si is s
       SOS-spezifische Spezialisierung des Uki::Handlers::Person-Handlers.
```

I think this is due to `nroff` thinking the output terminal is not a TTY, but I don't know how to tell it that, infact, it *is* a TTY.

Comment: What is the actual purpose of using `watch` to periodically output (the start of) the manual page every 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your issue is the rendering of the beautification done by `nroff`/`groff`.

To avoid this beautification, bypass `nroff`/`groff` and output your **pod** documentation into text with `pod2text` (this is a part of Perl distrib, so you should have it):

```
watch "pod2text <your_perl_withpod_file>"
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I lose the formatting information, which I'd like to preserve.

Comment: You are only losing the bold characters. The pod formatting is all there otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the manual page I came up with this solution:

`watch "perldoc -T -otext lib/Uki/Handlers/SOS.pm"`

Answer (score 0):

> "but I lose the formatting information, which I'd like to preserve."

It isn't that it thinks you aren't on a tty, it's that it thinks you are on a **really old** tty which does overstrike tricks through [grotty](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grotty), the back-end processor of groff. From the man page:

> Use the -c switch to revert to the old behaviour, printing a bold character c with the sequence 'c BACKSPACE c' and an italic character c by the sequence '_ BACKSPACE c'. At the same time, color output is disabled. The same effect can be achieved by setting either the GROFF_NO_SGR environment variable or using the 'sgr' X command (see below).

The problem is that you don't want `-c` or `GROFF_NO_SGR` set but for some reason it thinks one or both of them is.

Check your environment for `GROFF*`, and the `TERM` variable for sane values.

Comment: I'm using `urxvt-unicode` Verison `9.19-1` on an up-to-date archlinux. My environment has no settings concerning `GROFF*`. My `TERM` Variable is `TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color`, but it makes no difference when I set this to `xterm` (or switch to xterm completely).